# UITablieview with constantly changing values

Tags: uitableview

Is it possible to use a UITableView in such a way that it's cells update their content indepedantly from the CellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Example: Showing cells with a timer which includes milliseconds.

Refreshing the table view every (say) 10 milliseconds in order to update the timer's display value for each cell will surely not work, well...

Comment: Tricky if you use re-usable cells. But if you know that you don't have too many rows, then you could sub-class UITableViewCell and do whatever you wanted to....

Comment: Of course if you had the same timer in every cell, then just subclass the reusable cells

Comment: The cells are few, wont even need scrolling. Individual timers. So it will work to use a timer within the UITableViewCell subclass? Excellent! @MichaelL Mind posting your comment as an answer? I'll accept as soon as I confirmed that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky if you use re-usable cells. But if you know that you don't have too many rows, then you could sub-class UITableViewCell and do whatever you wanted to....

Answer (score 1):

Just create a customCell and make it observe to the timer change using NSNotification. Now whenever the timer changes, simply post a notification with the value. Let the cells observe and update by themselves.